# How to restore F1-F12 keys on sculpt mobile keyboard

Tags: keyboard, fn-key

The [sculpt mobile keyboard](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/sculpt-mobile-keyboard#details) is small and somewhat ergonomic. Sadly all the function keys have been replaced by the multimedia equivalent. This is very annoying for things I do: gaming and programming. I never use these multimedia keys, so it means pressing Fn every time.

So does anyone know how to make the F1-F12 keys default again?

Reason for using this keyboard:
It has no numpad allowing my mouse to be closer to my normal hand position and it's somewhat ergonomic unlike the other keyboards that dropped the numpad. I also have the [trulyergonomic](http://www.trulyergonomic.com/store/index.php) keyboard, which is much better. But I don't want to move it twice a day, so I leave it at work and I din't want to spend 200+ euro's on a keyboard again.

Comment: I am shocked and disappointed that the Fn keys are locked and there seems to be no way to fix this. I've been searching on the net for 3 hours and no avail. I am a software developer that really needs the Fn 1 to 12 keys.. not some crappy windows keys which I hardly touch with a 10 foot pole. Microsoft please fix this.

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard has a mechanical switch on the top right corner to choose between function keys or windows commands.